# How does type stability make Julia so fast?

Tags: types, runtime, julia

I've heard that type stability is what makes Julia so fast, while still being as expressive as other interpreted languages such as Python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type stability allows the compiler to determine the output types of a function directly from the input types at compile time. Because Julia specializes the compilation on every input type, this means that if all functions are type stable, the compiler can deduce the types of every value inside of a function call. When this occurs, Julia's JIT compiler will essentially create a statically typed version of the method and build the LLVM IR to compile that static version, where that static version is essentially the same assembly code as C compiled with clang (LLVM).

What this means is that, if the compiler can deduce the basic types on every variable, it will and it will emit code that forces those types to hold, just as though it was fully annotated C code. The way that Julia is dynamic is that when this doesn't hold, then it will "box" the variables, essentially creating a new type that says "I don't know what the type is" and add in code for forcing type checks and dispatch computations at runtime to handle the dynamicness. So if all type information is known, the dynamicness of Julia compiles away and ceases to even exist in the code that is ran.

This is also why multiple dispatch is so crucial to the language, since multiple dispatch then means that `f(x)` has a different method for `f(x::Float64)` (even if you don't specify the concrete version, the compiler will deduce and use that, called automatic type-specialization), and now that concrete version is more likely to be stable than the general version. Exposing multiple dispatch as a feature is really just allowing you to intercept this stage of the compilation and allow changing the type->code relationship.